# Understanding [name]も[name]よ

Tags: grammar, particle-も, particle-よ

From Oshi no ko chapter 142,

[image]

She wondered why Ruby decided to accept to take part in a kissing scene for a movie.

I don't get the nuance of ルビーもルビーよ here. It literally means "Ruby is Ruby." I checked English translation, it is understood as "I don't understand Ruby." I don't see where it came from.

Comment: I've already read this chapter but it's a very recent one. What do we think about spoilers in this SE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

よ is simply the feminine ending particle. If the speaker is a(n adult) male, it can be AもAだ.

The base meaning of AもAよ is *A is also...* Most often, it appears in the context where it is discussed who's to blame. It usually comes (implicitly) in pair with a preceding XもXだけど. For the particular context, it could be like

- キスシーンのある役を要求する監督も監督だけど、引き受けるルビーもルビーだ

(I don't know the manga and the scene, so this may not fit exactly). This says, the director requiring the kissing scene is to blame primarily, but Ruby is *also* to blame in accepting the direction. (To be clear, the director part is just made up. The point is that the character is saying that Ruby accepting the role is to blame - or at least not understandable, as suggested by なんでこんなの受けちゃうかな.)

---

An example:

- ２０過ぎて働かないのは問題だけど、親も親だよ (blaming a [NEET](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88) person from 3rd person perspective)

The first part makes clear that not working is a bad thing,then the second part states the parents are partially to blame too.

---

A related expression: どっちもどっち, which is often used in the sense that both are bad/to blame.

Comment: I know the manga and the scene and your example fits very well.